# Unity3d Time.deltaTime and framerate issue

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in which player can assign certain task to npc, and with task complexity it will take that much amount of  time (5 minutes for complex task and 1 minute for simple task). To achieve this I created a timer with Time.deltatime.

```
Starttime = Starttime + Time.Deltatime;
```

but as per unity docs deltatime is difference between two frames so now on pc game is running on 60 frames so it will takes 60 frames to complete one minute but on mobile it takes longer time than required , So please can anyone tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: Fix what? you copy/paste something from the documentation, state a requirement, but fail to ask a question and seem to think we write your program for you?

Comment: What should happen on the task time? If you only need a script to work then save the start time and check when the time is passed...

Comment: I think you missunderstood the docs. `Time.deltaTime` is for making you game framerate independant, so no matter how many frames you are running at, it will take the same time. E.g. for a 1 minute task at 60 fps it will take 3600 frames, at 30 fps it will take 1800 frames, but still exactly 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use Time.deltaTime or any similar function ever, for any reason - ever.

For beginners with Unity, for all timers and all issues relating to time, just use **Invoke**

Your code will look like this...

```
void Start()
 {
 Debug.Log("user begins task .. must complete in 60 seconds");
 Invoke("TimeIsUpForUser", 60f);
 } 

private void TimeIsUpForUser()
 {
 Debug.Log("time's up! user must be finished by now");
 }
```

It's that simple.

By way of example, your whole code may look something like this..

```
void Start()
 {
 ShowMiniPuzzleOnScreen();
 Invoke("TimeIsUpForUser", 60f);
 } 

private void UserHasPlacedFinalPieceOfPuzzle()
 {
 MessageScreen("Congratulations! You get 100 coins!");
 balance += 100;
 CancelInvoke("TimeIsUpForUser");
 }

private void TimeIsUpForUser()
 {
 HideMiniPuzzle();
 PlaySadMusic();
 MessageScreen("You suck! You are too slow. You lose 50 points.");
 balance -= 50;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Joe Blow for your help ,but I think I misunderstood the unity docs can you please tell me if Time.deltaTime is for make game framerate independant, so no matter how many frames it is running at, it will take the same time or not ?

Comment: cheers be sure to remember to use **Invoke**.  @paulp